# Re-Enable NVidia-Prime Icon in Lower Right Task Bar

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint 18.1 with the Cinnamon desktop on a Dell Inspiron 7559 with NVidia GPU.

I recently messed around with my NVidia packages (installed bumblebee only to quickly uninstall bumblebee due to prime conflicts). After this fiasco, the little NVidia icon on the bottom right of the task bar that indicated which GPU I was using has since disappeared.

I sniffed through the NVidia X Server Settings GUI to see if there was any obvious solution, but I fear I have come up dry. I tried the "Display Status Bar" option but that did nothing.

Is there a way to re-enable this small, but useful icon?

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted the bumblebee installation I purged some of my nvidia settings, this included a small piece of software called `nvidia-prime-applet`.

Reinstalling this software was done by the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime-applet
```

And then rebooting.